# How to check if date() function minus one?

Tags: php

Is it possible to check if the date `("j-1 F-1")`???

I'm a noob so some script would help! Postdate is in a format like: `14 October`.

```
if ($postdate == date("j F")) {$postdate = "today";} THIS WORKS...
```

But I need to check the `$postdate` for the `"yesterday`" value as well!

Q: How to check for yesterday? that is, date()-1 somehow.

Thanks again

Comment: What actually is your question?

Comment: <hint>Please don't "lol" around here.</hint>

Comment: @camran: Thanks for editing out the chat style. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
date('j F', strtotime('-1 day'));
```

Will retrieve the "yesterday" timestamp. So :

```
if ($postdate == date('j F', strtotime('-1 day'))) {$postdate = "yesterday";}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$yesterday = date('j F', mktime(0,0,0, date('m'), date('d')-1, date('Y')));
```

The "magic" is in the `mktime` call. I seriously advise you to read the relevant parts of the PHP manual: this is almost a verbatim duplication of [Example #3](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)!

Comment: +1 for "read the relevant parts of the PHP manual", +1 for dmathieu's comment (I'd add "and more reliable").

Answer (score 0):

use `strtotime` or `mktime` and then check if your date is between that value and todays timestamp.

```
if($date > strtotime('yesterday') && $date < time()) { echo 'yesterday or today' }

if($date > mktime(0,0,0,date('n'),date('j')-1) && $date < time()) { echo 'yesterday or today' }
```